# Data Driven Validation/Rule Engine in JAVA

Tags: json, drools, drools-guvnor

I have data and series of validation (Business logic) before I can use it further. Like following :-

```
{
    "site"      : "UK",
    "domain"    : "xyz.UK",
    "currency"  : "DOLLAR",
    "type"      : "unlimited",
    "limit"     : ""
}

{
    "site"      : "UK",
    "domain"    : "xyz.UK",
    "currency"  : "EURO",
    "type"      : "limited",
    "limit"     : "100"
}

{
    "site"      : "US",
    "domain"    : "xyz.COM",
    "currency"  : "DOLLAR",
    "type"      : "limited",
    "limit"     : ""
}
```

Validations FLOW is like

1. Domain validation

   Site = us >> domain = .com

   Site = uk >> domain = .uk
2. Currency validation

   Site = us >> currency = DOLLAR

   Site = uk >> currency = EURO
3. Type validation

   Site = us >> type = "only limited"

   Site = us >> type = "limited/unlimited"

   type = limited >> limit > 0

   type = unlimited >> limit == null

So only second JSON will pass the validations. First one have wrong Currency and 3 one limit is null.
More fields will keep on adding and the validations will keep on increasing. I dont want to put the validation in JAVA code
as in I have to change the code again and again. Is there any other way to save the validations/rules and there sequence in DB and 
fetch the validation/rules from DB to validate the data. If I need to change or add more I can modify DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the financial data set is available as a Java bean (and that there is a typo US/UK), the third validation can be written as:

```
rule "check type"
when
    Data( site == "US" && type == "limited ||
          site == "UK" && type == "limited || == "unlimited,
          type == "limited" && limit != null && limit > 0 ||
          type == "unlimited" && limit == null )
then
    // Data's type and limit is OK
end
```

This rule would "pass" the check. For determining what is wrong you'll need more rules, each of which pinpoints some fault.

Comment: What language is that supposed to be?

Comment: @kratenko It isn't "supposed to be", it is. See OP's tags.